# Populating UIComponents With JSON Data

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I gotta parse and discover an elegant way to work with my parsed data and also use it to populate correctly UIElements, such as, UITableViews, UICollectionViews and etc. I'll post below how I'm parsing and also the JSON file.

```
import Foundation

struct Contents : Decodable {

    let data : [Content]
}

struct Content : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let descricao : String
    let urlImagem : String


}
```

API Response file:

```
import Foundation


var audioBook = [Content]()


func getAudiobooksAPI() {

        let url = URL(string: "https://alodjinha.herokuapp.com/categoria")

        let session = URLSession.shared

        guard let unwrappedURL = url else { print("Error unwrapping URL"); return }

        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: unwrappedURL) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let unwrappedDAta = data else { print("Error unwrapping data"); return }

            do {



                     let posts2 = try JSONDecoder().decode(Contents.self, from: unwrappedDAta)
                         audioBook = posts2.data




            } catch {
                print("Could not get API data. \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

TableView file:

> How can I populate using the data I parsed? I really have difficult on doing that. I need an explanation to guide me on how to do it using an elegant way and also as a Senior Developer.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        getAudiobooksAPI()




    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return  ?????
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

               ???????

        return cell

    }
}
```

> JSON:

[***JSON Model***](https://alodjinha.herokuapp.com/categoria)

Comment: Please remove all those empty lines. Why do you do that?

Comment: Hello @meaning-matters! I did it just for you guys maybe be visualize the code better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your API Service with `completion Handler`

```
func getAudiobooksAPI(_ completion:@escaping ([Content])->Void) {

        let url = URL(string: "https://alodjinha.herokuapp.com/categoria")

        let session = URLSession.shared

     guard let unwrappedDAta = data else {  completion([Content]());  return}

        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: unwrappedURL) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let unwrappedDAta = data else { print("Error unwrapping data"); return }

            do {



                let posts2 = try JSONDecoder().decode(Contents.self, from: unwrappedDAta)
                completion(posts2.data)



            } catch {
                print("Could not get API data. \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion([Content]())

            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
```

And Use Like that

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

     var dataSource: [Content] = [Content]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



         getAudiobooksAPI { (data) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dataSource = data
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }




    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return  self.dataSource.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

             let content = self.dataSource[indexPath.item]

        return cell

    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Worked nice and clean lol. You have no idea how much you helped me, man.

Comment: Thank you so much! So, if I do this on a company as a Senior Dev I'll be good? There's any other cleaner way to work?

Comment: yes this God but you have to make separate layer for API , there is a-lot to do but for this target yes completion handler works good,

Comment: You mean like MVC?

Comment: yes architecture pattern Pattern you can work with MVVM